# Does parental conflict lead to genes combining important functions with functions only advantageous for one of the parents?

Tags: genetics, evolution, theoretical-biology, epigenetics, evolutionary-game-theory

In a sitation of a mother-father conflict of interests, the mother [might use](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5985782_Parental_conflict_does_not_necessarily_lead_to_the_evolution_of_imprinting) epigenetics to turn off some genes only advantageous for the father's genes and not her own. I thought a logical father's contra-strategy would be to bind the functions only advantageous to him to some of the genes crucial for them both, so that the mother couldn't turn these genes off.

Is there any evidence for a similar mechanism of "taking some genes hostage" in a situation of a conflict of interests?

Comment: While epigenetics is something the mother organism may control to some extent, I don't see how the father could do anything of the sort. Binding genes together requires genetic changes that take many generations, i.e., "father" in this case is not an organism but indication of the way the gene was transmitted.

Comment: @Vadim I broadened my question to any parent because I imagined it could be the case if the father's genes affected the chances of the fetus being miscarried.

Comment: It sounds like this question is asking about [imprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomic_imprinting). However, you don't specifically mention that term so perhaps you are unaware of the research on this subject? If so, there was a relevant review published last year in [PLOS Genetics](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1008970). A ["Learn Genetics" page](https://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/epigenetics/imprinting/) and  ["journal club" article in Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41580-020-00289-8) could also be of interest.